# Android ListView dynamic from .NET Web service

Tags: android, web-services, listview

In my android application I need populate the ListView of dynamic string with image and text taken on .NET web service.
If the ListView is static I don't have problem but can't if the ListView is dynamic.
Any suggestions?

code example ListView:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.xxxxx.com/WebService/GetNews";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "GetNews";
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://www.xxxxx.com/GetNews";
    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://www.xxxxx.com/GetNews.asmx";

    ListView list;
    String[] web = { "Google Plus", "Twitter", "Windows", "Bing", "Itunes",
            "Wordpress", "Drupal" };
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7 };                 


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                OPERATION_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try {

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "You Clicked at " + web[+position],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I tried this solution but the ListView is empty...:

```
try {

    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

    String ws = response.toString();
    Log.i("wsString", ws.toString());

    String wsnew = ws.replaceAll("<br />", "\n");
    Log.i("ws", wsnew);

    String[] wss = wsnew.split("\n");
    Log.i("wss0", wss[0].toString());
    Log.i("wss1", wss[1].toString());
    Log.i("wss2", wss[2].toString());

    final String[] web = { wss[1].toString() };

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "You Clicked at " + web[+position],
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

} catch (Exception exception) {

}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is how to pass dynamic variables string of web service within `String[] web` and `Integer[] imageId`

Comment: You need to parser value web, and imageId then update your adapter

Comment: And you need to do all the HTTP calls in an async thread not by overriding the ThreadPolicy in onCreate.

Comment: Please look edit in my first message